# Android: Multiple Dialog Boxes on One Activity

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have two `TextView`s in an `Activity` (but will be adding more).

When the user presses on a `TextView`, a `Dialog` appears that contains some text. However, I want the text content to change in the `Dialog` depending on which `TextView` was pressed.

(`onPrepareDialog()` comes up as a solution a lot but it is now deprecated)
The app is an information app. There is a "click here" option on different textviews which, when pressed, will each bring up a dialog box with different text content and a different title. Just wondering what is the best way to do this. Thanks!

Code so far....

```
 public class HomeDialogBox extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Message here - to change depending on textview pressed")
            .setPositiveButton("OK Button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
                        //This method will be invoked when a button in the dialog is clicked.
                }
            );

    builder.setTitle("Title to change depending on textview pressed ");
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please post your code as reference point? Thanks

Comment: just create a dialog every time the view is touched. You don´t need onPrepareDialog()....please show us what You have done..

Comment: use a proper approach for that , use EditText for entering data.

Comment: Why not just create a view overlapping and set View visibility to false on it when not used.  This would be much easier and make more sense than having a dialog interact constantly with the Activity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick responses. I have included some more detail. Apologies if there is a very obvious answer, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be possible to just create two seperate Dialog instances for each button?

Just have a method that creates a Dialog, and depending on which button is pressed create the dialog with the intended message using builder.setMessage

Answer (score 0):

### main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.oms.track.FinishedSingleItemView" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Large Text one"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:text="Large Text two"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:text="Large Text three"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

### MainActivity.java

```
TextView t1,t2,t3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    
    t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            showAlertDialog1(MainActivity.this, "text view1","touched text view 1", true);
        }
    });
    t2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showAlertDialog1(MainActivity.this, "text view2","touched text view 2", true);
        }
    });
    t3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showAlertDialog1(MainActivity.this, "text view3","touched text view 3", true);
    }
    });
}         

public void showAlertDialog1(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}